# Achieving a 6-second period for a PWM Wave using nRF52 Series PWM Driver in C

Tags: c, pwm, nrf52

I am working on a project using an nRF52 Series MCU, where I am aiming to produce a sinusoidal PWM wave with a total period of approximately 6 seconds using the nRF52 SDK v.15.3.0.

I have initialized the PWM with a base clock frequency of 250kHz and a top value of 4167, and I am using an array data[360] to hold the scaled and normalized duty cycle values representing one cycle of a sine wave.

For example:
4167/250000 = 0.016668 * 360 (number of items in the array) would be approximately to 6 seconds.

However, this is where I failed to set the logic. When I check the wave effect in the logic analyzes, it takes aprox 1.2 seconds and I don't understand why.

I would appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

Part of the code:

```
uint16_t data[360];
uint16_t duty_cycle;

nrf_pwm_clk_t base_clock;

const nrf_drv_pwm_t m_pwm0 = NRF_DRV_PWM_INSTANCE(0);

nrf_pwm_values_wave_form_t seq_values_wave_form = {
    .channel_0 = 0,
    .counter_top = 4095,
};

nrf_pwm_values_t seq_pwm_values;
nrf_pwm_sequence_t seq_wave_form;

void pwm_init_config()
{
    uint8_t prescaler_setting = 0;

    switch (prescaler_setting)
    {
    case 0:
        base_clock = NRF_PWM_CLK_250kHz;
        break; // 32MHz / 128
    }

    nrf_drv_pwm_config_t const config0 =
        {
            .output_pins =
                {
                    LED_1,
                    NRF_DRV_PWM_PIN_NOT_USED,
                    NRF_DRV_PWM_PIN_NOT_USED,
                    NRF_DRV_PWM_PIN_NOT_USED,
                },
            .irq_priority = APP_IRQ_PRIORITY_LOWEST,
            .base_clock = base_clock,             // Frequency
            .count_mode = NRF_PWM_MODE_UP,        // operating mode of the pulse generator counter
            .top_value = 4167,                    // count, Period = top_value / Hz
            .load_mode = NRF_PWM_LOAD_INDIVIDUAL, // mode of loading sequence data from RAM
            .step_mode = NRF_PWM_STEP_AUTO};      // mode of advancing the active sequence
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(nrf_drv_pwm_init(&m_pwm0, &config0, NULL));
}

// Initiliaze the sequence structure with values for the waveform
void initialize_basic_data()
{
    int size = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        double radian = i * (M_PI / 180); // Convert degree to radian as sin function in C uses radian
        double sin_value = sin(radian);   // get sin value which will be in range [-1, 1]
        // Normalize and scale sin_value to 15-bit integer value, using only 11 upper bits for amplitude
        uint16_t scaled_value = (uint16_t)((sin_value + 1) * 0x03FF); // 0x03FF = 1023, the maximum 10-bit value
        data[i] = scaled_value << 4;                                  // left shift by 4 to use the upper 11 bits
    }

    seq_wave_form.values.p_wave_form = data;
    seq_wave_form.length = NRF_PWM_VALUES_LENGTH(data);
    seq_wave_form.repeats = 0;
    seq_wave_form.end_delay = 0;
}

void wave_effect()
{
    initialize_basic_data(); // Inicializa os valores de data com a onda senoidal
    nrf_drv_pwm_simple_playback(&m_pwm0, &seq_wave_form, 1, NRF_DRV_PWM_FLAG_LOOP);
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is a guess, but maybe seq_wave_form.repeats defaults to 1000 (or 1024) if you don't set it to something positive. Try setting it to 4167?

Comment: That would not make it, the .repeats are the number of times that each duty cycle should be repeated (after being played once).

This would cause the Period to be like minutes

Comment: Don't know then sorry. Have you confirmed the clock speed is correctly set to 250KHz and not 1MHz?

Comment: Yes:

    switch (prescaler_setting)
    {
    case 0:
        base_clock = NRF_PWM_CLK_250kHz;
        break; // 32MHz / 128
    }

Comment: If you change the first line to uint16_t data[1440]; does it take more like 6s?

Comment: I cannot do that, this would be 0.016668 seconds x 1440 = 24 seconds. Anyway, I am out of the office already.

I will continue on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was uint16_t data[360]

This was required to be defined as `nrf_pwm_values_individual_t data[360];`.
The PWM driver would function unexpectedly without defining the proper struct.